# Does using VBOs and VAOs increases the performance in integrated chips which has shared memory

Tags: c++, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

In our current project we are using [this intel integrated chip](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/atom-z36xxx-z37xxx-datasheet-vol-1.pdf). Even in the spec it is told that OGL ES 2.0 is supported, we weren't using VBOs and VAOs(no glGenBuffers, glBindBuffers) and thus we were using Client side vertex buffering.

We come up with the idea that if we use VBOs we will have a better performance. But now I am thinking about it; if GPU and CPU is already sharing the same memory using VBOs makes any difference. Because in my mind VBOs helps because we do not need to transfer the data to GPU each time but in this case when the memory shared I am not sure if it will make any difference.

My question is with my hardware in which memory is shared, using VBOs will boosts the performance or not ? And if there is a difference for VBO performance between integrated chips and having cpu and gpu separated  what are they ?

Comment: This really depends on the hardware and drivers, the only way to know for your target platform is to bench it. (Shared memory architectures can still make a difference between CPU and GPU memory: caching policies might change for example)

Answer (score 1):

With client side vertices, at best the driver must be allocating some space and copying the vertices, because it's got to allow for the possibility that the client will modify the data before the GPU consumes the vertices.

With VBOs in the best case, that copy can be skipped and for VBOs that never change it's safe to assume you'll get a performance boost (albeit maybe a small one).

However, for vertices that are constantly changing (like a CPU driven particle system, or dynamically generated quads for fonts/huds) it can be a bit tricky using VBOs efficiently. You need to use some sort of strategy for recycling the buffers (orphaning, double-buffering, triple-buffering, GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT) and any option you choose seems to perform surprisingly poorly on some subset of Android devices. For constantly changing vertices, client side vertices may not be the best, but at least they're rarely a performance black-hole.

Answer (score 0):

IN my opinion, using VBOs/VAOs has no disadvantage and is the current way to do it.

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Client-Side_Vertex_Arrays

"Before VBOs, there were plain old vertex arrays. This means that your vertices and vertex attributes and indices are in RAM. Of course, this doesn't give the best performance since every time you want GL to draw, the driver has to upload the vertices to the GPU."

That said, OpenGL is just a specification, so at the end of the day it all depends on how your driver implements these.